# Visual c++ no intellisense, how do i see what is inside a class/namespace/library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Im new to c++ and i dont have anyidea what functions/variables are in the System namespace and so on. I know that there is no intellisense in CLR projects at least in 2010. What im asking is were is the documentation? or a good place to get it? is there one build into visual c++ or do i have to constantly google it?

Comment: The documentation can usually be found in the "Help" menu.

Comment: In my day we had to open a book... ok, not really, but in some people's day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the .NET Framework class library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg145045.aspx

However, you state you are looking to develop in C++. C++ does not target the .NET Framework unless you are using C++/CLI to develop managed applications.

Comment: @JavaNewb At it's core, it doesn't really target a framework. There are standard libraries that are a part of the language, and certainly several frameworks that developers can use to facilitate writing their application such as STL, boost, MFC, etc.